# Rails test error when attempting to find associated model in test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I am making an online library system with Ruby on Rails. Currently users can sign up, but to do so they must first choose a type of subscription plan.

In the end, the best way I found to do this, was to pass a `plan_id` like so:

```
config/routes.rb

get 'subscribe/paperback2u', to: 'members#new', :plan_id => 1
get 'subscribe/paperback4u', to: 'members#new', :plan_id => 2
get 'subscribe/paperback6u', to: 'members#new', :plan_id => 3
```

Then, `members/new.html.erb` pulls the `form` partial, which looks like this:

```
<%= form_with(model: member, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% plan_id = params[:plan_id] %>

  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= form.label :first_name, "First Name" %>
    <%= form.text_field :first_name, 
                        id: :member_first_name,
                        :class => "form-control",
                        :required => true %> 
  </div>

  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= form.label :last_name, "Last Name" %>
    <%= form.text_field :last_name,
                        id: :member_last_name,
                        :class => "form-control",
                        :required => true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= form.label :address_line_1, "Address Line 1" %>
    <%= form.text_field :address_line_1,
                        id: :member_address_line_1,
                        :class => "form-control",
                        :required => true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= form.label :address_line_2, "Address Line 2" %>
    <%= form.text_field :address_line_2,
                        id: :member_address_line_2,
                        :class => "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= form.label :town %>
    <%= form.text_field :town,
                        id: :member_town,
                        :class => "form-control",
                        :required => true %>
  </div>
```

And the other fields for the member model.

Then we get to:

```
 98 <%= form.hidden_field :plan_id, value: params[:plan_id] %>

100 <% if form.object.new_record? %>
101   <%= render 'stripe-form' %>
102 <% end %>
```

I don't think `line 98` is doing anything, to be honest.

Then the `stripe-form` partial looks like this:

```
1  <div class="text-center">
2    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button btn-primary"
3      data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
4      data-description="Subscribe to ReadAll Library"
5      data-amount=<%= (Plan.find(params["plan_id"].to_i).display_price) * 100 %>
6      data-currency="gbp"
7      data-panelLabel="Subscribe for"
8      data-label="Subscribe"
9      data-locale="auto"></script>
10 </div>
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Error:
MembersControllerTest#test_should_get_new:
ActionView::Template::Error: Couldn't find Plan with 'id'=1
    app/views/members/_stripe-form.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_members__stripe_form_html_erb___374722773566915779_70180218242520'
    app/views/members/_form.html.erb:101:in `block in _app_views_members__form_html_erb__2640496602018942691_70180179508500'
    app/views/members/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_members__form_html_erb__2640496602018942691_70180179508500'
    app/views/members/new.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_members_new_html_erb___3025732295195500162_70180218177380'
    test/controllers/members_controller_test.rb:16:in `block in <class:MembersControllerTest>'
```

The error I get if I add `puts response.body` in the tests is: "Plan must exist". Which it does! I have 3 different plans in my `plans` table. Each one has an ID, and everything works when I actually run it. It's just the test that doesn't work. I'd scrap the test if I could, but I need it as documentation for a project.

Finally, here's my `Plan.rb` and `Member.rb`

```
`plan.rb`

 class Plan < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :members
 end

`member.rb`

   class Member < User
1    require 'stripe'
2 
3    before_save :set_type
4 
5    belongs_to :plan
6 
7 
8    def set_type
9      self.type = "Member"
10   end
11
12 end
```

And the schema for the two:

```
create_table "plans", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "stripe_id"
  t.string "nickname"
  t.decimal "display_price"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.string "product"
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  bunch of user attributes (first_name, address, etc)
  t.string "type" (members is a users type)
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.string "remember_digest"
  t.string "customer_id"
  t.bigint "plan_id"
  t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  t.index ["plan_id"], name: "index_users_on_plan_id"
end
```

I'm out of ideas. I appreciate any help you guys can give me. Cheers.

Comment: Not related to your question, but is that a real need to separate this problem in different URLs? You could easily use only on route instead of 3 to choose which plan the new user will get or let the user choose it.

Comment: From this line: "ActionView::Template::Error: Couldn't find Plan with 'id'=1". It seems that your test is trying to retrieve from the database the Plan object with id equal to 1, instead of choose which Plan the user will use (which is just pass as parameter the id). From that, I would say your problem comes from having 3 URL to represent the same problem. I don't know from the top of my mind a solution to the problem you are having.

Comment: @PedroGabrielLima I just couldn't find a way to associate an existing plan with a user. This is the only way I could get it to work. Since I don't want to create a new plan (so no nested form), I just want to give the new member, an existing plan's ID in the plan_id column. Any suggestions?

Comment: From "I just couldn't find a way to associate an existing plan with a user", well, there is a way. You just need to add a way to the user select what plan they want, and send that to your controller with all the others information. I will post an answer with a general example of this.

Comment: I post another alternative to the way you can let the user choose the plan. To help you with your real problem, did you create the fixtures to the model Plan? If you don't, that is may the raise of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view, if you want that your user choose from the form, you could add the select input and let the user select what plan they want. But it's all possible that you pass this information through URL, as you already did.

View:

```
<%= form_with(model: member, local: true) do |form| %>

  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= form.label :first_name, "First Name" %>
    <%= form.text_field :first_name, 
                        id: :member_first_name,
                        :class => "form-control",
                        :required => true %> 
  </div>

  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= form.label :plan, "Choose your plan" %>
    <%= form.select :plan_id, 
        Plan.all {|p| [ p.name, p.id ]}, 
        { include_blank: false, selected: form.object.plan_id }, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit "Salvar", class: "btn btn-primary" %>  
<% end %>
```

I believe the rest you already did it. In the controller you add to the white list of params the plan_id, and in your model you add model relations as has_many and belong. P.s: I didn't test this.

Comment: Thanks Pedro! I'll be using this instead. I ended up using collection_select instead, as it wasn't rendering the names or IDs. Gracias chamo!

Comment: @SHorvath, glad that it helped you!